# React component composition

Tags: reactjs

I trying to build a simple slide show using react (I am learning react) and have a question regarding the component composition/information flow.

I have a *slides* component which has two child components. One child, the *slideContainer*, displays the slide and the other component, the *slideNavigation* displays the navigation buttons (back/next).

The *slides* component receives the slides collection as prop and has the currentSlide as State. The *slideNavigation* component receives the currentSlide, the slides collection and the setCurrentSlide callback as props.

The *slideNavigation* component determines the new currentSlide based upon the button that was clicked, the slide collection and the currentSlide. The new currentSlide is returned to the *slides* component using the callBack. The *slides* component updates the state accordingly and passes it to the display component, which displays the new slide. See the code of the *slides* component below.

[image: slides.js]

My question: It seems a bit weird to determine the new currentSlide in the navigation component, pass to back to its parent which passes it again to the navigation component where it just came from.  Am i doing something wrong, are the components correctly composed??

Comment: Please add code instead of images.

Answer (score 1):

You should add callbacks/props to your slidenavigation like:

```
onPrevSlideButtonClicked

onNextSlideButtonClicked
```

Then in your parent component you will add callbacks for each event and calculate the new slide (because that is where all your info is stored).

Answer (score 1):

The only change that you can make is to move the determination of the new slide, from the `slideNavigation`  to the parent `slides` component.

The `slides` component should hold the state and be responsible for managing it. It contains 2 dumb child components, the `slideContainer` and the `slideNavigation`. These child components should know nothing about what is going on; the Container should just show what it receives from the parent and the navigation should just return events that occur (the next and previous button clicks)

It should be the job of the parent `slides` container to manage the state transition by sending props down to the `slideNavigation` component, which would be tied to the buttons for the next and previous actions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I put the responsibilities incorrectly indeed. I never will make this error again, i hope :)